# Sequence and related function

Tags: sequences-and-series

As part of an assignment I need to show that $a < a_n < b$ for $n \geq 2$, with $a<b$ in the sequence
$$
a_n=\frac{a+(n-1)b}{n},\quad n \in\mathbb{N}
$$

and define the function

$$
f_n(x) =
\begin{cases} 
      0, & x \in [a,a_n] \\
      \frac{x-a_n}{b-a_n}, & x \in ]a_n,b] \\
\end{cases}
$$

and graph it.

I haven't worked on many problems with sequences and I don't know where to start. I also find the function quite bewildering.

I am mostly looking for hints. Anything would be helpful.

Comment: for the inequality, figure out why $na < a + (n-1)b$ holds and deduce the left side of the inequality. Any function in the given sequence of functions is a concatenation of two lines. Figure out where the function is equal to 0 and where it is equal to 1 and what happens in between.

Comment: Note that $a_n=(1/n)a+(1-1/n)b = a-(1-1/n)a+(1-1/n)b=a+(1-1/n)(b-a)$.

Comment: Also $a_n=\frac{a-b+bn}{n}=\frac{a-b}{n}+b=b-\frac{b-a}{n}$